# execute/run mysql via Sublime Text in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2

I am a newbie programmer (if i can be even considered a programmer) trying to teach myself mySQL.  After reading through plenty of pages and watching multiple youtube videos i came across Sublime Text and i really like the functionality of it.  i have been trying to configure sqlexec package available on github: https://github.com/jum4/sublime-sqlexec

I have added the code available on the documentation page (http://lubriciousdevelopers.github.io/projects/sublime-sql-exec/) under "Settings-User".  I am getting a connected to the database, i can see all the tables within the DB and can bring up the query line as well.  the status line at the bottom of sublime text-2 says "running sql command" and then nothing. no results.  and the query is simple "SELECT * FROM ".

any tips/advice on this would be greatly appreciated.  i can provide any additional details if needed.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess you should see an error somewhere, since that's not really a valid query. You might try something valid, like `SELECT NOW();` and see if anything different happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I tried multiple queries. the above query was just an example.  what i meant to say there was i just ran a simple "select * from" query nothing exotic.

I recently uninstalled sublime and installed it again and installed SQLExec. the connection occurs because i see the tables.the query box opens allowing me to write queries.and it looks like it's executing. but documentation says "results in the output panel. and i can't find this "output panel" to save my life.  this is where i am stuck.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  many thanks in advance.